# Own common libraries in own dart/flutter projects in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, reusability, project-structure

I'm working on one project for some time now on flutter. Part of the source code has been designed so that it can be used again as is in other projects.

I'm working with **Visual Studio Code**.

Now I'm creating a second project. I'd like to organize folders this way:

```
Parent folder
   Project1 folder
   Project2 folder
   my_library
```

Is it possible to add the library folder to the projects, as it is not inside their respective folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this isn't straightforward for beginners. So I summed up the proposed solutions here (I provide the names out of fairness, and follow related potential discussions below each one).

1. From Richard Heap:

> In pubspec.yaml of project 1, refer to the library as:

```
dependencies:
  my_library:
    path: ../my_library
```

2. From me:

In *../my_library*, add a specific *pubspec.yaml*. Something like:

```
name: my_libraries
description: my own common libraries

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"
  
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

3. From me:

Drag and drop (maybe there's a menu) your *my_libraries* folder from a file explorer to the VSCODE Explorer panel, and choose "add folder to workspace". Of course, all dependencies to external libraries used in *my_libraries* must be specified in its own *pub_spec.yaml* file.

Remarks:

- I added source files in my_libraries/lib/. Don't know if the *lib* sub-directory is mandatory.  Didn't take time to test without, and I like better to keep the same structure in my_libraries than in projects.
- in project (and my_library) source files, to import *my_library* source files, just do as:

  import 'package/my_library/xxx.dart'

where xxx.dart is the file to import.

Answer (score 1):

In `pubspec.yaml` of project 1, refer to the library as:

```
dependencies:
  my_library:
    path: ../my_library
```

Comment: Indeed but, although being the required good start, this answer is incomplete. I discovered that ../my_library needs its own pubspec.yaml file. Then the question remains its required content.